# Why did it take 2 hours to switch to a standby VAX?

Tags: history, maintenance, vax

According to [this section](http://whiteworld.com/cyreenikland/books/surfing/surf-03g.htm) of an excellent book on the history of Novell,

> I had actually started a business attempting to do some phases of what we are doing here at Novell. My plan was to develop to a typical $50-million to $100-million manufacturing environment [producing] a computer-based system with certain levels of fault tolerance[Footnote 1] that would allow me to run 24 hours a day for $250,000 as a system, and I was aimed at doing just that kind of business.

> The reason that I had a compelling interest in doing that was that I had run three other companies doing someplace in the $50-million level of business, and to run the business I had to run computer systems which cost about $1 million to maintain any level of security around running the factory without losing time. So I would typically buy two minicomputers, [DEC] VAXes as it turns out, and put them in hot standby so that if one failed the other one could be switched over as quickly as possible—and it usually took not less than two hours—so that I could continue to run the business.

Presumably nowadays, switching over to a standby machine is done automatically in a matter of milliseconds, whereas back in the eighties in the golden age of the VAX, it would involve someone going over and manually unplugging cables from one machine and plugging them into the other.

But... that still feels like it should only take a few minutes.

What exactly took two hours?

Comment: Not sure if that has even a reasonable answer . if it has, it's just about this very specific site, its very specific setup, the people involved, their preparation and readiness. Also, flipping between standby systems is nothing new. Likewise systems existed since almost ever. I remember /370 based networke with fail safe nodes and constant monitoring that could switch between message frames to standby, so not even dropping any connection.

Comment: Not enough info.  What, for example, did he mean by 'hot standby'? How were disks configured?  Dual-ported drives (but that's single point of failure, unless the disks were also mirrored)?  Were the two VAXen clustered together?  I assume not, given the "2 hours".

Comment: may very well have had to do with peripherals - including controllers talking to machines, since the context is "running a factory".  or it could have just been this guy blowing smoke to his biographer.

Comment: What "failed" in the scenario?  If for example it was a head crash, then it might well take 2 hours to restore from backup on the other machine (which seems to give the lie to 'hot standby').

Comment: @davidbak I agree, it was almost certainly peripherals.  I worked with minicomputers that were designed for true hot standby, and the peripherals ran through what was in essence an immense electronic "gang switch" that would allow the good computer to take all of the peripherals, including digital and analog I/O that would be needed to control a factory, away from the failed computer.  If the author's VAX lacked that kind of hardware, then it could rearranging connections that took two hours.

Comment: This is curious as the VAX was renowned for its VAXCluster capability which allowed multiple CPUs with shared disk and other peripherals that should have mitigated a lot of that switchover.

Comment: @WillHartung  VAXClusters weren't available until VMS 4.0 in 1984, according to Wikipedia, so it looks like this "hot spare" setup predated that.  (I ran a 2-node VAXCluster in the early 2000s and cutover time was indeed minimal; basically just "update DNS" to send connections to the functioning box.)

Comment: And even then, in 1984 you'd need a star CI coupler, and likely HSC disks, which is more than 'a couple of minicomputers'.  Ethernet (NI) clusters didn't happen until a couple of years after that.

Comment: I've heard that NOTAM took 90 minutes to reboot on Jan 11 2023, which run on some mainframe.

Comment: Switch what to a standby VAX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't there, so I don't know why it took two hours.  If I had to invent a plausible scenario,  it would be along these lines.

The VAX is a transaction processor with a database that reflects the cumulative effect of all the transactions.  Something like a banking database.  The standby VAX is not fed the transactions on a live basis.  Instead, transactions completed by the main VAX are logged in a growing file of transactions that can be re-done if needed.  Once a day, the standby VAX is updated with yesterday's transactions.

When the unscheduled cutover to the standby VAX occurrs,  some transactions that have been done on the main computer have to be redone on the standby VAX before it can go live.  Going live without those transactions would be counterproductive.

In the case described, it took almost two hours to complete those transactions and bring the database on the standby VAX up to synch with the last valid status of the main VAX.

Again, this is pure speculation,  but things like this have occurred.

Comment: Plausible, but in that situation it seems a bit misleading to call the spare VAX a 'hot' standby.

Comment: @Dave agreed.  People misuse terms all the time.

Comment: Sounds like you're describing "warm standby".  But I agree, terms might have been misused, and also distinctions made today may not have been so precise in the past.

Comment: I remember a real hot standy that was activated on Sep 11th.  They lost about 20 seconds worth of transactions.  And, by coincidence, it was on a couple of VAXen.

Comment: Speaking of hot standbys that are not so hot,  I wonder what hppened to the FAAs information system yesterday?